# Count days between min and max dates with overlaps and gaps in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, date, powerpivot

```
ITEM CODE   PRICE   PRICE FROM  PRICE TO
ABC123  $100.00     11/18/2016  11/25/2016
ABC123  $100.00     12/2/2016   12/9/2016
ABC123  $100.00     12/9/2016   12/16/2016
ABC123  $100.00     12/23/2016  12/30/2016
ABC123  $100.00     12/30/2016  1/6/2017
ABC123  $100.00     1/6/2017    1/13/2017
ABC123  $100.00     2/1/2017    2/28/2017
ABC123  $100.00     3/3/2017    3/10/2017
ABC123  $100.00     3/10/2017   3/17/2017
ABC123  $100.00     3/17/2017   3/24/2017
ABC123  $100.00     4/1/2017    4/30/2017
ABC123  $100.00     4/7/2017    4/14/2017
ABC123  $100.00     4/12/2017   7/31/2017
ABC123  $100.00     4/14/2017   4/21/2017
ABC123  $100.00     4/28/2017   5/5/2017
ABC123  $100.00     5/1/2017    5/31/2017
ABC123  $100.00     5/5/2017    5/12/2017
ABC123  $100.00     5/19/2017   5/26/2017
ABC123  $100.00     5/24/2017   9/30/2017
ABC123  $100.00     6/1/2017    6/30/2017
ABC123  $100.00     8/1/2017    8/31/2017
ABC123  $100.00     9/1/2017    9/30/2017
```

I've attached a sample of my data set above.  I'm trying to calculate using PowerPivot the number of days an item is at a given price taking into account gaps and overlaps.  In the example above, I have an item that is listed at the same price for several different date ranges.

I've tried making a few different price from and price to columns, by taking the earliest date, 11/18/2016, to the next end date 11/25/16.  Then identify the next earliest price date, 12/2/2016 to the next end date 12/16/2016.  I've been successful at this until I get to the last data consecutive time frame that starts at 4/1/2017 and ends with 9/30/2017.  Also, I don't believe my several column method is very efficient.

Is there any way to calculate the number of unique days (without gaps or overlaps) that an item is at the same price in PowerPivot?

Thank you!

Comment: looks like a simple formula like `=SUMIF(B:B,100,D:D)-SUMIF(B:B,100,C:C)+COUNTIF(B:B,100)` would do the job...

Comment: This a sample of my data set. My overall data set has over 15,000 items with several different prices per item - ex: an item was on a weekly sale, etc.

Comment: by changing my formula a bit to `=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,F1,B:B,G1)-SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,F1,B:B,G1)+COUNTIFS(A:A,F1,B:B,G1)` you can set the item to F1 and price to G1 to get the count of days... should be fast, even with a lot of datasets ;)